Interpreting Centered 2-Way PDP
I have recently used scikit-learn's PartialDependenceDisplay.from_estimator function to display cICE plots in combination with PDPs using the kind parameter. To investigate feature interactions, I have created 2-way PDPs with the centered parameter set to true as I have figured that it would behave similarly to 1-way PDP + ICE. However, after comparing the resulting plot to a non-centered 2-way PDP, the contour lines are almost entirely different, i.e. it's almost as if I have compared different feature pairs and the interactions have vanished (in the non-centered 2-way PDP). After trying to find anything related to centered 2-way PDP and reading through the documentation, which states

centered: If True, the ICE and PD lines will start at the origin of the y-axis.

, I am unsure how centered 2-way PDPs can be interpreted. Why do they differ so much from normal PDPs? An example: The centered 2-way PDP shows 2 small groups for specific value pairs of the features, i.e. some patterns that the model has saved. However, after using a normal 2-way PDP those groups disappear and the model's output seems to depend on only one of the two features. I couldn't find any related papers or explanations on the internet regarding centered 2-way PDPs which is why I am grateful for any clarification.

Please consider including screenshots of the plots, where the axes are labelled appropriately. That would provide a more concrete example for readers to work with.
